# Making the screen darker than the lowest brightness setting

Tags: brightness

I'd like to make the screen in Ubuntu darker than the lowest brightness setting. Is there any way to do this besides inverting the screen brightness?

Comment: [This solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181501/191971) works best for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it can get darker for me. When I slide the bar all the way down, it almost completely blacks the screen out.

Either way, try lowering the brightness setting of your monitor, perhaps?

Comment: When I slide the bar all the way down, the screen becomes noticeably darker, but remains almost blindingly bright. I'd like to make it darker to stop the screen brightness from ruining my vision.

Comment: Also, I am using a Lenovo Z560.